# Display element from a list to its own variable

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I need to pull approval comments. A form will go through a few approvals. So I want to pull that comment. Currently all comments I put in one variable. So my user needs to delimited by their own report type. So may I know how to do that? Like approval 1, their comments will go to approval comment 1, same goes to others. I do like this. But it shows an error out of bounds. I think because there is no data in locations 2-6. But I need whenever approval 1 approve/ reject it will go to Approval_Comment_1__c, and others

```
trigger pullCommentsApproval on RPR__c (before update) {
    String myApproval;
    Map<Id, RPR__c> oppMap = new Map<Id, RPR__c>([
        Select (Select IsPending, ProcessInstanceId, TargetObjectId, StepStatus, OriginalActorId, ActorId,Actor.Name, RemindersSent, Comments, IsDeleted, CreatedDate, CreatedById, SystemModstamp 
                From ProcessSteps where StepStatus IN ('Approved','Rejected') ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) From RPR__c WHERE Id IN : Trigger.new]);
    
    for(RPR__c opp: Trigger.new) {
        RPR__c opp1 = oppMap.get(opp.Id);
        opp.Approver_Comments__c = '';
        for (ProcessInstanceHistory processStep : opp1.ProcessSteps) {
            myApproval += 'Comments: ' + processStep.comments + ' . Status: ' + processStep.StepStatus + ' . Date: ' + processStep.CreatedDate +' . Commentor Name: ' + processStep.Actor.Name + '‽';
            List<String> res = myApproval.split('‽');
            for(integer i=0; i<res.size(); i++){
                opp.Approval_Comment_1__c = res[1];
                opp.Approval_Comment_2__c = res[2];
                opp.Approval_Comment_3__c = res[3];
                opp.Approval_Comment_4__c = res[4];
                opp.Approval_Comment_5__c = res[5];
                opp.Approval_Comment_6__c = res[6];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use your for-loop currently, just assigning variables, assuming that the list is size 7. Try this approach (
also note, that you should be certain, that you have Approval_Comment_i__c for the res.size(). If you're not sure about it, then you should perform a check):

```
Map<String, SObjectField> fieldsMap = RPR__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (Integer i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
    if (fieldsMap.containsKey('Approval_Comment_' + String.valueOf(i + 1) + '__c')) {
        opp.put('Approval_Comment_' + String.valueOf(i + 1) + '__c', res[i]);
    }
}
```